# Ubuntu does not open

Tags: boot, 20.04

[image]Hello! I have a big problem I tried this on ubuntu, second photo and now ubuntu does not work, picture 1. What can I do because I am scared.[image]

Comment: Cause you downgraded some packages that might be the issue, i would suggest you boot from the CD and then chroot to you system and  then update the packages, if still does not solve your problem then restore the backup.

Comment: And if I don t have a backup it is over right?

Comment: You have a backup of your personal data that you value. If not, then before proceeding with anything else, boot a live CD, mount the partition containing that unprotected data, and make a backup.

Comment: @al3x4ndru1 - you should *always* keep a backup - obviously - but it is very likely you can get your files back, even if your system is broken and no backup. Boot into a live usb session, find your files on the hard drive (you may need to mount it manually), and back up all your data to a separate external drive, then see if you can fix it. Good luck.

Comment: Error messages in your first screenshot suggest something may have happened with your `/etc/fstab` configuration file - you may want to include the contents in your question. That is also something you will need to do from a live session or a recovery prompt.

Comment: @Al3x4ndru1 No, just dont give up, first you need BOOT from CD then remove STEAM package and install broken packages. if that does not solve your issue, mount another hard drive and backup every required files that you have, then clean install and restore the files back to the new one.

Comment: I have done it sorry to disturbed you!